# Perl PAWS SelectObjectContent - "Precondition Failed"

Tags: perl, amazon-s3, amazon-s3-select

I receive a "Precondition Failed" error when I try to run:

```
my $obj = $s3->SelectObjectContent(
    Bucket              => 'MyBucket',
    Expression          => 'SELECT * FROM s3object s',
    ExpressionType      => 'SQL',
    InputSerialization  => {
        JSON => {
            Type => 'LINES'
        }
    },
    Key                 => 'MyKey',
    OutputSerialization => {
        JSON => {}
    } );
```

I followed https://metacpan.org/pod/Paws::S3::SelectObjectContent#RequestProgress-=%3E-Paws::S3::RequestProgress

I have successfully called "GetObject" using my bucket and key, so those are not responsible for the error.

Comment: When I [try](https://pastebin.com/KWdY0siT) this I get a [Bad request](https://pastebin.com/WrD20jSQ) error. I am looking into the issue.

Comment: Added [bug report](https://github.com/pplu/aws-sdk-perl/issues/403)